# how to overload Times and Plus for matrix multiplication in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to overload `Times` and `Plus` for matrix multiplication in mathematica, for example, let `Times` be `BitAnd`, and Plus be `BitOr`, then do the matrix multiplication.

Is there anyway to do this in a simple way, without rewriting my own matrix multiplication?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that redefining built-in `Times` will break any Mathematica functions that expect standard behavior from `Times` on matrices. A safer alternative is to define `MyTimes` and use Notation package to give it own appearance and shortcut

Comment: Isn't the idea of overloading providing an operator functionality for additional data types? In this case, Times already is defined for matrices. So, do you want to lose this predefined meaning and overwrite this with the BitAnd and BitOr behaviors? Why don't you just use the latter functions? Or do you want to use their symbols? There are better solutions for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is what you want to alter - the behavior of `Times` and `Plus`, or `Dot`. Generally, `Block` trick is often the simplest way. In this case, since `Dot` does not call high-level `Plus` or `Times`, you can do:

```
mat1 = {{1,2},{3,4}};
mat2= {{5,6},{7,8}};
Block[{Dot = Inner[BitAnd,#1,#2,BitOr]&},
  mat1.mat2]

{{3,0},{5,2}}
```

But note that this is effectively re-implementing the matrix multiplication (using `Inner`) - there is no other way since `Dot` is implemented internally and does not use `Plus` or `Times`.

Comment: One should not under any circumstances overload Plus or Times. Leonid Shifrin's method would be a good way to go about this particular task. Though changing Dot inside Block is not really necessary for general usage, since you can just define myDot or some such.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for making this clear. I am guilty of having done that (overloading Times or Plus) a couple of times in the past (mostly when I was learning mma), but I always had a bad feeling about it.