# Show in explicitly viewable form in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Continuing with my [matrix multiplication question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252179/how-to-overload-times-and-plus-for-matrix-multiplication-in-mathematica), I want to show the following expression in explicit viewable form in mma:

[image: the form I want to show in mma]

Even if in the case I give a11, ..., b11, ... explicit numbers, I still want it to be (0&&1)||(1&&1) in unevaluated form. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a really good idea (overloading internal functions and all; and && is And not BitAnd, which you wanted to use in the previous question), but you asked for it and you get it:

```
CircleTimes[a_?MatrixQ, b_?MatrixQ] := 
 Inner[HoldForm[BitAnd[##]] &, a, b, HoldForm[BitOr[##]] &]

Unprotect[BitAnd];
Unprotect[BitOr];
BitAnd /: Format[BitAnd[a_, b_]] := a && b;
BitOr /: Format[BitOr[a_, b_]] := a || b;
Protect[BitAnd];
Protect[BitOr]

mat1 = Array[Subscript[a, #1, #2] &, {2, 2}];
mat2 = Array[Subscript[b, #1, #2] &, {2, 2}];
```

[image: output of newly defined CircleTimes]

The advantage of defining the operation as CircleTimes is that you get the CircleTimes symbol and operator for free.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
Inner[And, Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {2, 2}], 
  Array[Subscript[b, ##] &, {2, 2}], Or] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**Edit**. Having followed up on your previous question, I think you might consider

```
Inner[HoldForm[And[##]] &, amat, 
  bmat, HoldForm[Or[##]] &] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`(0&&1)||(1&&1)` does not evaluate, so I do not see the problem.  For `True` and `False` have you tried using HoldForm?

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to define your own matrix *wrapper*.  The wrapper approach has the advantage that you can overload as many built-in functions as you like without impacting any other functionality.

Let's start by defining a wrapper called `myMatrix` that displays itself using `MatrixForm`:

```
Format[myMatrix[m_]] ^:= MatrixForm[m]
```

Next, we'll overload the `Times` operator when it acts on `myMatrix`:

```
myMatrix[m1_] myMatrix[m2_] ^:= myMatrix[Inner[And, m1, m2, Or]]
```

Note that both definitions use `^:=` to attach the rules to `myMatrix` as up-values.  This is crucial to ensure that the regular built-in definitions are otherwise unaffected.

Armed with these definitions, we can now achieve the desired goal.  To demonstrate, let's define two matrices:

```
m1 = myMatrix[Array[Subscript[a, Row[{##}]]&, {2, 2}]]
```

[image: mathematica output]

```
m2 = myMatrix[Array[Subscript[b, Row[{##}]]&, {2, 2}]]
```

[image: mathematica output]

The requested "explicitly viewable form" can now be generated thus:

```
Row[{m1, m2}] == m1 m2
```

[image: mathematica output]

... or, if you prefer to reference `Times` explicitly on the left-hand side of the equation:

```
With[{m1 = m1, m2 = m2}, HoldForm[m1 m2] == m1 m2]
```

[image: mathematica output]

Next, we'll assign random boolean values to each of the matrix elements:

```
Evaluate[First /@ {m1, m2}] = RandomInteger[1, {2, 2, 2}];
```

... and then generate the explicitly viewable form once again with the assignments in place:

```
With[{m1 = m1, m2 = m2}, HoldForm[m1 m2] == m1 m2]
```

[image: mathematica output]